# Using tracing in a multithreaded Java server

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, jaeger, opentracing

I am having trouble with using tracing in my multithreaded application.

**background:**

In my SpringBoot application I have a function "service" which calls another function "innerService", and I want to trace each function with its own span.
I am implementing OpenTracing with Jaeger in the following way:

AppConfig.java:

```
@Bean
public static JaegerTracer getTracer() {
    io.jaegertracing.Configuration.SamplerConfiguration samplerConfig = io.jaegertracing.Configuration.SamplerConfiguration.fromEnv().withType("const").withParam(1);
    io.jaegertracing.Configuration.ReporterConfiguration reporterConfig = io.jaegertracing.Configuration.ReporterConfiguration.fromEnv().withLogSpans(true);
    io.jaegertracing.Configuration config = new io.jaegertracing.Configuration("myService").withSampler(samplerConfig).withReporter(reporterConfig);
    return config.getTracer();
}
```

I then use it in one of my apps' services:

```
@GrpcService
public class ServiceA extends ServiceAGrpc.ServiceAImplBase {
     private final Tracer tracer;

     @Autowired
     public ServiceA(Tracer tracer) {
         this.tracer = tracer;
}

@Override
public void service(Request request, StreamObserver<ResultGrpc> responseObserver) {
    Span span = startSpanInScope(this.tracer, "service");
    ...
    innerService();
    ...
    span.finish();
}
```

the function that returns a span:

```
public static Span startSpanInScope(Tracer tracer, String spanName) {
    if (tracer == null) {
        return null;
    }
    Span span = tracer.buildSpan(spanName).start();
    Scope scope = tracer.scopeManager().activate(span);
    return span;
}
```

When sending a single request to the service, everything seems fine and the spans appear one inside the other:

[image]

However, when I send multiple requests at once, using multiple threads, the spans interfere one another:
[image]

I guess it happens because whenever a span starts it becomes the child of the currently active span, even if this span is from another thread. I don't understand why, since I read that the ScopeManager is by default a ThreadLocal object.

Can anyone suggest a solution to this? I want a separate trace for each thread, which will show the spans for "service" and "innerService" as its child.

Comment: You should use `try { ... } finally { }` to ensure that the scope that started are then closed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to close your scope too (`scope.close()`) and not only the span which might be the reason why your trace continuous. Closing the scope automatically finishes the span. Furthermore, you can directly create a span as an active one in a single command: `Scope scope = tracer.buildSpan(spanName).startActive(true)`. This way, you don't have to manually call the `scopeManager`.

Due to the fact that the `Scope` class implements the `AutoClosable`interface, you can use try-resource blocks in order to prevent missing a scope from closing:

```
try (Scope scope = this.tracer.buildSpan("service").startActive(true)) {
    innerService();
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I see that the startActive method is deprecated in the latest JaegerTracer. Is the another way to achieve this behavior?